# How to get Tab's parent (TabLayout) from TabSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

I have two TabLayouts on the same fragment and each of them holds two tabs:

```
TabLayout studentsTab = view.findViewById(R.id.students_tab);
studentsTab.addTab(studentsTab.newTab().setText("one"));
studentsTab.addTab(studentsTab.newTab().setText("two"));
studentsTab.setTag("students");

TabLayout teachersTab = view.findViewById(R.id.teachers_tab);
teachersTab.addTab(teachersTab.newTab().setText("one"));
teachersTab.addTab(teachersTab.newTab().setText("two"));
teachersTab.setTag("teachers");
```

and instead of creating two setOnTabSelectedListener listeners i've implemented TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener by :

```
studentsTab.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
teachersTab.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
```

and now i have this method:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
// detect which TabLayout?
}
```

and I want to figure which tab triggered the tab selection. Is it studentsTab or teachersTab?

I tried to check if tab.getTag().equals("students") but the tab.getTag() is null.
When i debug the app i have the TabLayout on tab.mParent but it's not accessible.

I couldn't find a way to do it. Any help to find the parent would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag associated with your tabs before you add them to the `TabLayout`.  If you add a tag of "student" or "teacher" to the correct tab, then you can reference that information in the `onTabSelected()`.

Check out the docs: [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html) specifically looking at the `getTag()` and `setTag()`.

Comment: I actually tried to do it before i posted the question but the getTag is always null. so i figured that the setTag is for the layout and getTag is for the tab itself.

Comment: Pretty sure I have used this method before and was able to see the associated tag that I added to the tab.  The doc also clearly states that the setTag function is used to "give this tab an arbitrary object to hold for later use". @user2396640

Answer (score 0):

Try setting contentDescription for each tab like this

```
for(int i=0; i<studentsTab.getTabCount; i++) {
   TabLayout.Tab tab = studentsTab.getTabAt(i);
   tab.setContentDescription("Text");
}
```

And then, in the onTabSelected method get the contentDescription

```
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    tab.getContentDescription();
}
```